# *args and other parameters in decorated function in python

Tags: python-3.x, parameters, parameter-passing, decorator

I have the following script that works fine. The decorator `on_or_off` takes the value from `on_switch` from the function and execute if its value is `True`.

```
import pandas as pd
import ctypes
import sec4_analysis as analysis

# Main class
######################################################################
class Analysis_ProjectX_Demographic(analysis.Analysis_ProjectX):
    def __init__(self):
        super()
        super().__init__()

    def demographic_analytic_steps(self):
        self.import_parent_ref_data()
        self.import_master_data()
        self.recategorize_var(on_switch=True)
        self.result_in_plaintext(on_switch=True)
        self.result_in_csv(on_switch=True)

    # Decorators
    def on_or_off(func):
        def wrapper(self, on_switch, *args):
            if on_switch:
                func(self, on_switch, *args)
        return wrapper

    # Core class functions
    @on_or_off
    def recategorize_var(self, on_switch=False):
        self.df_master_filtered = self.recat_binary(self.df_master_filtered, 'INDEX_RURAL', 'INDEX_RURAL_CAT', 0, 'URBAN', 1, 'RURAL')
        self.df_master_filtered = self.recat_age(self.df_master_filtered, 'INDEX_AGE', 'INDEX_AGE_CAT')

    @on_or_off
    def result_in_plaintext(self, on_switch=False):
        df_dict = {
            'TxGroup':self.df_master_filtered, 
            }
        for df_key, df in df_dict.items():
            print ('Dataset name: {}'.format(df_key))
            print ('Unique patients, n: {}'.format(df['PHN_ENC'].nunique()))
            self.descriptive_num_var_results(df_key, df, 'INDEX_AGE')
            self.descriptive_cat_var_results(df_key, df, 'INDEX_AGE_CAT')
            self.descriptive_cat_var_results(df_key, df, 'INDEX_RURAL_CAT')
            self.descriptive_cat_var_results(df_key, df, 'INDEX_SEX')

    @on_or_off
    def result_in_csv(self, on_switch=False):
        pass

    # Helper functions
    def recat_binary(self, df, old_var, new_var, old_val1, new_val1, old_val2, new_val2):
        df.loc[df[old_var] == old_val1, new_var] = new_val1 
        df.loc[df[old_var] == old_val2, new_var] = new_val2 
        return df

    def recat_age(self, df, old_var, new_var):
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=19.00)&(df[old_var]<25.00), new_var] = '19-24'
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=25.00)&(df[old_var]<30.00), new_var] = '25-29'
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=30.00)&(df[old_var]<35.00), new_var] = '30-34'
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=35.00)&(df[old_var]<40.00), new_var] = '35-39'
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=40.00)&(df[old_var]<45.00), new_var] = '40-44'
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=45.00)&(df[old_var]<50.00), new_var] = '45-49'
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=50.00)&(df[old_var]<55.00), new_var] = '50-54'
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=55.00)&(df[old_var]<60.00), new_var] = '55-59'
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=60.00)&(df[old_var]<65.00), new_var] = '60-64'
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=65.00)&(df[old_var]<300.00), new_var] = '65/above'
        return df

x = Analysis_ProjectX_Demographic()
x.demographic_analytic_steps()
```

However, the decorated functions are supposed to be free to have any number of parameters besides the `on_switch`. When I introduce more parameter `some_text` in the `result_in_plaintext.()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import ctypes
import sec4_analysis as analysis

# Main class
######################################################################
class Analysis_ProjectX_Demographic(analysis.Analysis_ProjectX):
    def __init__(self):
        super()
        super().__init__()

    def demographic_analytic_steps(self):
        self.import_parent_ref_data()
        self.import_master_data()
        self.recategorize_var(on_switch=True)
        self.result_in_plaintext(some_text='This is done', on_switch=True)
        self.result_in_csv(on_switch=True)

    # Decorators
    def on_or_off(func):
        def wrapper(self, on_switch, *args):
            if on_switch:
                func(self, on_switch, *args)
        return wrapper

    # Core class functions
    @on_or_off
    def recategorize_var(self, on_switch=False):
        self.df_master_filtered = self.recat_binary(self.df_master_filtered, 'INDEX_RURAL', 'INDEX_RURAL_CAT', 0, 'URBAN', 1, 'RURAL')
        self.df_master_filtered = self.recat_age(self.df_master_filtered, 'INDEX_AGE', 'INDEX_AGE_CAT')

    @on_or_off
    def result_in_plaintext(self, some_text, on_switch=False):
        df_dict = {
            'TxGroup':self.df_master_filtered, 
            }
        for df_key, df in df_dict.items():
            print ('Dataset name: {}'.format(df_key))
            print ('Unique patients, n: {}'.format(df['PHN_ENC'].nunique()))
            self.descriptive_num_var_results(df_key, df, 'INDEX_AGE')
            self.descriptive_cat_var_results(df_key, df, 'INDEX_AGE_CAT')
            self.descriptive_cat_var_results(df_key, df, 'INDEX_RURAL_CAT')
            self.descriptive_cat_var_results(df_key, df, 'INDEX_SEX')

        print(some_text)

    @on_or_off
    def result_in_csv(self, on_switch=False):
        pass

    # Helper functions
    def recat_binary(self, df, old_var, new_var, old_val1, new_val1, old_val2, new_val2):
        df.loc[df[old_var] == old_val1, new_var] = new_val1 
        df.loc[df[old_var] == old_val2, new_var] = new_val2 
        return df

    def recat_age(self, df, old_var, new_var):
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=19.00)&(df[old_var]<25.00), new_var] = '19-24'
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=25.00)&(df[old_var]<30.00), new_var] = '25-29'
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=30.00)&(df[old_var]<35.00), new_var] = '30-34'
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=35.00)&(df[old_var]<40.00), new_var] = '35-39'
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=40.00)&(df[old_var]<45.00), new_var] = '40-44'
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=45.00)&(df[old_var]<50.00), new_var] = '45-49'
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=50.00)&(df[old_var]<55.00), new_var] = '50-54'
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=55.00)&(df[old_var]<60.00), new_var] = '55-59'
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=60.00)&(df[old_var]<65.00), new_var] = '60-64'
        df.loc[(df[old_var]>=65.00)&(df[old_var]<300.00), new_var] = '65/above'
        return df

x = Analysis_ProjectX_Demographic()
x.demographic_analytic_steps()
```

It gave this error:

```
line 16, in demographic_analytic_steps
self.result_in_plaintext(some_text='This is done', on_switch=True)
TypeError: wrapper() got an unexpected keyword argument 'some_text'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*args` parameter you're using in your `wrapper` function only supports additional arguments passed in as positional arguments. It doesn't support arbitrary keyword arguments. If you want to match keyword arguments, you need to use `**kwargs` (either instead of or in addition to `*args`). Otherwise you'd need to change how you call the function, to pass `some_text` as a positional argument instead of  a keyword argument.

Note that the order of the positional arguments matters! You'll need to put the `*args` later in the argument list than other positional arguments, which means that `on_switch` needs to be the first argument, not the second one if you are passing them positionally. This is one reason to favor keyword arguments, as their order does not matter. You can even make *keyword-only* arguments, by putting them after the `*args` parameter in the function declaration (or after a `*` by itself, if you don't need `*args` at all). If you want the most general support possible, I'd suggest:

```
# Decorators
def on_or_off(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, on_switch, **kwargs):  # on_switch is keyword only now!
        if on_switch:
            func(self, *args, on_switch=on_switch, **kwargs) # note you may want to return here
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass:
    def on_or_off(func):
            def wrapper(self,*args, **kwargs):
                if kwargs['on_switch']:
                    func(**kwargs)
            return wrapper
    @on_or_off
    def test(on_switch = False,some_text="This is done"):
          print(f' "Test" Function executed with on_switch = {on_switch} and some_text {some_text}')

obj = MyClass()
obj.test(on_switch = True, some_text="Abhijeet")
```